# How to apply a javascript function to a multiple div Classes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

I have a function that creates a gallery of flickr sets pulled from my flickr account. I am getting the set numbers from a database and using a while loop to display the first image from  the set. Each element of the table has the same class and i am applying a Javascript function to them. Unfortunately each table element is displaying the same photo, the last one pulled from the database.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var flickrUrl="";
        $('.gallery_table_data').each(function(){
                flickrUrl = $(this).attr('title');
                $('.flickr_div').flickrGallery({

                    "flickrSet" : flickrUrl,
                    "flickrKey" : "54498f94e844cb09c23a76808693730a"
                });



        });
    });
```

and the images dont show up at all? can anyone help??
Here is the flickr jquery in case that's the problem:

```
var flickrhelpers = null;

(function(jQuery) {

jQuery.fn.flickrGallery = function(args) {

    var $element = jQuery(this), // reference to the jQuery version of the current DOM element
        element = this;         // reference to the actual DOM element

    // Public methods
    var methods = {
        init : function () {
            // Extend the default options
            settings = jQuery.extend({}, defaults, args);

            // Make sure the api key and setID are passed
            if (settings.flickrKey === null || settings.flickrSet === null) {
                alert('You must pass an API key and a Flickr setID');
                return;
            }



            // CSS jqfobject overflow for aspect ratio
            element.css("overflow","hidden");

            // Get the Flickr Set :)
            $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?format=json&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&photoset_id=" + settings.flickrSet + "&api_key=" + settings.flickrKey + "&jsoncallback=?", function(flickrData){

                var length = 1;
                var thumbHTML = '';

                for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
                    var photoURL = 'http://farm' + flickrData.photoset.photo[i].farm + '.' + 'static.flickr.com/' + flickrData.photoset.photo[i].server + '/' + flickrData.photoset.photo[i].id + '_' + flickrData.photoset.photo[i].secret +'.jpg'

                    settings.imgArray[i] = photoURL;
                    settings.titleArray[i] = flickrData.photoset.photo[i].title;
                }



                // Get the position of the element Flickr jqfobj will be loaded into
                settings.x = element.offset().left;
                settings.y = element.offset().top;
                settings.c = settings.x + (element.width() / 2);
                settings.ct = settings.y + (element.height() / 2);





                // When data is set, load first image.
                flickrhelpers.navImg(0);

            });

        }
    }

    // Helper functions here
    flickrhelpers = {
        navImg : function (index) {
            // Set the global index
            currentIndex = index;




            // Create an image Obj with the URL from array
            var thsImage = null;
            thsImage = new Image();
            thsImage.src = settings.imgArray[index];

            // Set global imgObj to jQuery img Object
            settings.fImg = $( thsImage );

            // Display the image
            element.html('');
            element.html('<img class="thsImage" src=' + settings.imgArray[index] + ' border=0>');

            // Call to function to take loader away once image is fully loaded
            $(".thsImage").load(function() {
                // Set the aspect ratio
                var w = $(".thsImage").width();
                var h = $(".thsImage").height();
                if (w > h) {
                    var fRatio = w/h;
                    $(".thsImage").css("width",element.width());
                    $(".thsImage").css("height",Math.round(element.width() * (1/fRatio)));
                } else {
                    var fRatio = h/w;
                    $(".thsImage").css("height",element.height());
                    $(".thsImage").css("width",Math.round(element.height() * (1/fRatio)));
                }

                if (element.outerHeight() > $(".thsImage").outerHeight()) {
                    var thisHalfImage = $(".thsImage").outerHeight()/2;
                    var thisTopOffset = (element.outerHeight()/2) - thisHalfImage;
                    $(".thsImage").css("margin-top",thisTopOffset+"px");
                }



                if (settings.titleArray[currentIndex] != "") {
                    $(".flickr_count").append(settings.titleArray[currentIndex]);
                }


            });


        },
        toggleUp : function() {
            $("#flickr_thumbs").slideUp("slow");
        }
    }

    // Hooray, defaults
    var defaults = {
        "flickrSet" : null,
        "flickrKey" : null,
        "x" : 0, // Object X
        "y" : 0, // Object Y
        "c" : 0, // Object center point
        "ct" : 0, // Object center point from top
        "mX" : 0, // Mouse X
        "mY" : 0,  // Mouse Y
        "imgArray" : [], // Array to hold urls to flickr images
        "titleArray" : [], // Array to hold image titles if they exist
        "currentIndex" : 0, // Default image index
        "fImg" : null, // For checking if the image jqfobject is loaded.
    }

    // For extending the defaults!
    var settings = {}

    // Init this thing
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
        methods.init();
    });

    // Sort of like an init() but re-positions dynamic elements if browser resized.
    $(window).resize(function() {
        // Get the position of the element Flickr jqfobj will be loaded into
        settings.x = element.offset().left;
        settings.y = element.offset().top;
        settings.c = settings.x + (element.width() / 2);
        settings.ct = settings.y + (element.height() / 2);


    });



}


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: There's no while loop anywhere in your code.

Comment: did you happen to read on how to use this plugin?

Comment: the while loop is working perfectly, its not the problem

Comment: @joseph i did but i am altering it, the code given is for single galleries only, but i have adapted it to display several sets in a table

Comment: can you rather paste the HTML you are working on, the data of the pictures than the plugin code?

Comment: @rudawg, post your real code (including the while loop), with no "alteration".  If you knew what the problem was you wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: `live("each"` does not make sense.  The first parameter should be an event type like `click`.

Comment: sorry @MatthewFlaschen i should have posted it all, i just figured that since the while loop was working it wasn't the problem, i added the code above :)

Comment: @rudawg, thanks.  That answers charlietfl's question about the HTML structure.

Answer (score 2):

The big problem is in your `$.each` loop.  I am going to assume the plugin will work for all the elements you are looping over although have doubts that it will.

WHen you select `$('.flickr_div')` on each pass it affects all the elements in page with that class...so only the last pass of loop is valid

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var flickrUrl="";
        $('.gallery_table_data').each(function(){
                flickrUrl = $(this).attr('title');

                /* this is your problem , is selecting all ".flickr_div" in page on each loop*/
                //$('.flickr_div').flickrGallery({

                /* without seeing your html structure am assuming 
                next class is inside "this"

                try: */

                $(this).find('.flickr_div').flickrGallery({

                    "flickrSet" : flickrUrl,
                    "flickrKey" : "54498f94e844cb09c23a76808693730a"
                });

        });
    });
```

**EDIT**  This same concept of using `find()` should also be refactoered into code within the plugin. Plugin should have all ID's replaced with classes.

Plugin really does not look well constructed for multiple instances within a page

Comment: i replaced the id's with classes in the plugin and used the find function but it still didn't work. Do you think its not possible to do what i'm trying to??

Comment: it likely is but will require reasonable level of understanding of html  tree structure and jQuery and how to use console for checking errors

Comment: well i have some understanding of them, im just under pressure a bit with time so it would be nice to know where to start?

Comment: where did plugin come from...is there a link can see how markup works?

Comment: plugin really doesn't appear to be well suited for multiple instances without a rewrite

Answer (score 1):

I might be wrong here, but won't this (in your `flickrGallery` object)

```
$("body").append('<div id="flickr_loader"></div>');`
```

create multiple elements with the same ID? And the same for images in `flickrhelpers`:

```
element.html('<img id="thsImage" src=' + settings.imgArray[index] + ' border=0>');
```